# Right aligned text in minipage vs. longtabu

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabu

After some brute-force attempts I found out that I could right-align two lines in a longtabu cell as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\desc}[2]{ \begin{minipage}[t]{6em} \hfill \textbf{#1}\\  \footnotesize \raggedleft #2 \end{minipage} }

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{r l}
 \desc{Frequency}{kHz} & \bfseries Callsign \\ \toprule
\endhead
2500 & WWV \\
3330 & CHU
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: Both lines aligned to the right]

When I change the second line to use `\hfill` it is aligned to the left:

```
\newcommand{\desc}[2]{ \begin{minipage}[t]{6em} \hfill \textbf{#1}\\  \footnotesize \hfill #2 \end{minipage} }
```

[image: With hfill for both lines]

And if I try to use `\raggedleft` for the whole minipage, like this:

```
\newcommand{\desc}[2]{ \begin{minipage}[t]{6em} \raggedleft \textbf{#1}\\  \footnotesize  #2 \end{minipage} }
```

then the document does not compile anymore. Why not? In any Office program I would just select the cell content and press the “right aligned” button, is LaTeX really that complicated?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want the output to look like, but it seems you are after using `\multicolumn` to adjust the alignment of a single cell, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \toprule
    \bfseries Frequency & \bfseries Callsign \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{kHz} \\
 \midrule
  2500 & WWV \\
  3330 & CHU \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that `longtabu` (and `tabu`) have some 'unusual' interface choices, and for creating a demo I've stuck with the standard `tabular` environment.